# Crumbly linseed oil putty

Tags: windows

I've recently glazed an acrylic sheet window with linseed oil putty, however it appears to have leaked.
I left it un painted for about 3 weeks to allow to dry, but it went crumbly.

What did I do wrong?
Should I use beading and some form of silicone sealant going forward?

I've lost confidence in putty.

Comment: Out of curiosity, was it an old container of putty? And are you planning on using oil-based paint on top?

Comment: It wasn't old, but it was hard ish and extremely sticky when applied. I'm using Farrow and ball water based paint. The resess the acrylic sheet went into was pre painted before the sheet went in.

Comment: Linseed oil is a drying oil, so it has a definite shelf life if exposed to air at all.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, linseed oil based putty should have worked well.

Something clearly went wrong, which might have been the product itself (too much time on the shelf or temperature cycling before you bought it) or a failure to knead it to an even consistency.

If it was me, I’d buy more of the same (linseed versus water-based), possibly from a supplier that turns stock more frequently and try again. Be sure to knead it thoroughly. Part of that is because it’ll be hard to get the oily residue off your existing work, and if you were to switch to latex or something else, bonding might be compromised.

Couple of other notes: scuff the paint surface that the putty is supposed to stick to. Use an oil based primer on the putty before topcoating with whatever you want.